# Karma complains about missing provider in component, but provider is not directly injected into component

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I have an Angular application and when running unit tests with Karma, I get an error in saying that there is a missing provider for the Store in a component.
The store is not directly injected into the component, but into a service that is injected into the component.

If I import the StoreModule into the component, the error disappears, but I shouldn't have to do that as the component does not require the store directly.

Error:

Error: StaticInjectorError(DynamicTestModule)[StoreRootModule -> Store]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[StoreRootModule -> Store]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for Store!

Component

```
export class TestComponent {
    constructor(private testService: TestService) {}
}
```

Service

```
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class TestService {
    constructor(private store: Store<AppState>) {}
}
```

Component unit test

```
class MockTestService {

}
describe('TestComponent', () => {
    let component: TestComponent;
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<TestComponent>;
    let resetMemorablePhraseService: MockTestService;

    beforeEach(async(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            declarations: [TestComponent],
            imports: [
                // StoreModule.forRoot({}) // adding this line gets rid of the error
            ],
            providers: [{
                provide: TestService, useClass: MockTestService
            }]
        })
            .compileComponents();
    }));

    beforeEach(() => {
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TestComponent);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
        fixture.detectChanges();
        service = TestBed.get(TestService);
    });
}
```

Comment: you need to inject the module

Comment: why? The component itself does not depend on the module.

Comment: Indeed it depends on the Module, everything in angular is created under module

Comment: Are you referring to the StoreModule?

Comment: yeah, wherever your provider belongs to

Answer (score 0):

I found out the cause

If the parent component have a child component that has dependency to some service

It should need to be added to the TestBed.configureTestingModule as well

example:

child.component.ts

```
// ChildComponent has dependency to AnyService
@Component({
    selector: 'app-child',
    template: 'I have dependency from a service'
})
export class ChildComponent {
    constructor(private anyService: AnyService) { }
}
```

parent.component.ts

```
// ParentComponent has no dependency from AnyService
// but since ChildComponent a.k.a "<app-child></app-child>" is embedded here,
// it will also be the dependency of this component
@Component({
    selector: 'app-parent',
    template: `
<h1>I don't have dependency from any service</h1>
<app-child></app-child>
`
})
export class ParentComponent { }
```

I hope this helps all readers out there having the same problem

Answer (score -1):

If you are using any component,provider inside any other module, you need to import that particular Module under imports,

Otherwise it will not find the particular provider and it will throw the error. The above problem is usual. To solve it import the Module.

Comment: what module are you referring to? As described above the component that not use the store.